# Google Sheets intersection query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to write an intersection query in Google Sheets that lists all the rows in sheet 1 that contain a cell in sheet 1, column A, that matches at least one cell in sheet 2, column P

This is the first time I've tried writing a more advanced formula on Google Sheets, using a combination of Sheets functions and the Google Visualization API Query Language. I'm just starting to learn the syntax and everything and I'm sure I'm messing things up so I hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong. My current query is:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:T, "SELECT * WHERE (VLOOKUP(A, 'Sheet2'!P, 1, FALSE) IS NOT NULL)", 1)
```

Comment: What output are you getting? What output are you expecting?

Comment: `(VLOOKUP(A, 'Sheet2'!P, 1, FALSE)` is not a valid Google Query clause. As a Google Sheets formula it has reference errors as `A` and `'Sheet2'!P` aren't valid references.

Comment: I'm getting an error, likely due to the issues Rubén stated. I'm expecting (hoping for...) a subset of rows from sheet 1 that have a column A cell value in common with a column P cell from sheet 2.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 17 times. It doesn't include enough detail to be certain about the spreadsheet structure and the data types to be handled with the formula, among other missing details.

Answer (score 1):

Michael, try this for your QUERY():

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!P:P,1,FALSE))),Sheet1!A:T,"")}, "Select * Where Not Col1 = ''"))`

Comment: I visited this question because Community user bumped it because the question has this answer, which did not get any votes. Community user has bumped this question 17 times. Not all the questions should be answered. Ref. [answer]. The resolution of a recent discussion about the site's "research policy" mentioned that Web Applications is not a help desk. [Referred Meta discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/88163). Please let me know if you would be interested in exploring other ways to participate.